# 'where' statement to dynamic field

Tags: mysql, substring, left-join, where-clause

Good Day!, I am facing problem with some mysql command.

as per my below example I want to get data as follows

```
SELECT c.*, SUBSTRING_INDEX(v1.c_value, ',', -1) AS e_status
FROM reg_emp AS c
LEFT JOIN default_values AS v1 ON c.emp_status = SUBSTRING_INDEX(v1.c_value, ',', 1) AND v1.category = 'emp_status'
where e_status = 'On Duty'
```

But is doesn't work for me, even with v1.e_status or c.e_status

Please keep in your mind, I dont want to make it like `where c.emp_status = '1'`

Kindly see the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42bf4/2)

Hope you can understand my question.

Thank you,

Regards,

Sameera Silva

Comment: what is your desired result?

Comment: what is the problem? what exactly do you mean by "doesn't work for me"?

Comment: I got an correct answer from [fancyPants](http://stackoverflow.com/users/447489/fancypants)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a SQL statement the `SELECT` clause is evaluated after the `WHERE` clause. Therefore you have to repeat the formula in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT c.*, SUBSTRING_INDEX(v1.c_value, ',', -1) AS e_status
FROM reg_emp AS c
LEFT JOIN default_values AS v1 ON c.emp_status = SUBSTRING_INDEX(v1.c_value, ',', 1) AND v1.category = 'emp_status'
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(v1.c_value, ',', -1) = 'On Duty'
```

The order of operations is

1. FROM
2. WHERE
3. GROUP BY
4. HAVING
5. ORDER BY
6. SELECT

You can't have aliases in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Very big thank for your quick answer and nice issue describe.